# Apache Camel SFTP : Auth cancel for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password'

Tags: apache-camel, jsch

I am trying to connect a SFTP server with Private Key but I am getting this error. (Private Key works with WinSCP and Filezilla)

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://xxxxx@xxxx:22
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:138) ~[camel-ftp-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:230) ~[camel-ftp-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.prePollCheck(RemoteFileConsumer.java:75) ~[camel-ftp-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:126) ~[camel-file-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:203) ~[camel-support-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:117) ~[camel-support-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel for methods 'publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password'
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:499) ~[jsch-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.tryConnect(SftpOperations.java:161) ~[camel-ftp-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.task.BlockingTask.lambda$run$0(BlockingTask.java:40) ~[camel-support-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.task.ForegroundTask.run(ForegroundTask.java:94) ~[camel-support-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.task.BlockingTask.run(BlockingTask.java:40) ~[camel-support-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:136) ~[camel-ftp-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

I tried two SFTP server and I can connect one server with same configuration. Here is my SFTP router;

```
JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-dss");
JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa");
JSch.setConfig("kex", JSch.getConfig("kex") + "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256");
        
byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64("base64_key");
getContext().getRegistry().bind("senderPrivateKeyArrRegistry", privateKeyBytes);


from("sftp://xxxxx@xxxxx:22//?username=xxxxx&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&privateKeyPassphrase=xxxxxx&privateKey=#senderPrivateKeyArrRegistry&minDepth=1&recursive=false&antInclude=xxx&exclude=&sortBy=file:modified&noop=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&disconnect=true")
.process(exchange -> {
    System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
});
```

I tried to change Jsch library with "com.github.mwiede" but no luck. Also I tried add "preferredAuthentications=publickey" to route but same error.

Camel Version : 4.0.1

```
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH_0.2.11
CheckCiphers: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
CheckKexes: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512
CheckSignatures: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed448
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
server proposal: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
server proposal: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
server proposal: ciphers c2s: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
server proposal: ciphers s2c: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
server proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
server proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
server proposal: compression c2s: none,zlib@openssh.com
server proposal: compression s2c: none,zlib@openssh.com
server proposal: languages c2s: 
server proposal: languages s2c: 
client proposal: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ext-info-c
client proposal: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
client proposal: ciphers c2s: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
client proposal: ciphers s2c: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
client proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
client proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
client proposal: compression c2s: none
client proposal: compression s2c: none
client proposal: languages c2s: 
client proposal: languages s2c: 
kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
ssh_eddsa_verify: ssh-ed25519 signature true
Host 'xyz123.com' is known and matches the EDDSA host key
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
SSH_MSG_EXT_INFO received
server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Next authentication method: publickey
Authentications that can continue: password
Next authentication method: password
Login trials exceeds 0
Disconnecting from xyz123.com port 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was caused by the value used for passPhrase containing inappropriate characters.

If you configure the endpoint as follows, this problem is solved.

```
....&privateKeyPassphrase=RAW("+passphrase+").to(...)
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode` might be more robust solution.